# how to getElementbyid for Another HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, eel

Can someone please explain how/why this behavior ..

I am writing an app using eel. eel starts with page1.html. also there is another page called page2.html.
but it is not loaded till I press on some link.

My Problem is, I need to insert some values in page2.html before I click on the link and open it.
but in `Javascript`, each time I apply `Getelementbyid`. i receive null response.
I have added eel.js in all html pages also all other `Javascripts`in all .html pages are in the same `init` folder.

Comment: You can't get an element by id that is not rendered in the DOM. The line document.getElementById(...) means accessing an element that is currently being displayed. Are you using HTML5? You can simply use sessions to pass value between pages using HTML5. Am not sure about eel :(

Comment: Is there a way to load the pages in background ? so i can show them anytime later ?

Comment: There's no way doing that. You can load pages only when you need them. I think you are worrying about passing the value before loading the page. You can easily pass them via the URL or using sessions as I mentioned and then set the values using JavaScript when the page/body is loading, so that you can display the content relevant to the value you passed.

Comment: actually, my concern is .. i want page2 to become for all logs which happen on page1, so whenever this page2 opens, it shall contain all the logs which happened and will happen in page1. this is my concern :( but am not familiar with passing via URL or using sessions. so if there an online example. Thanks in advance. and excuse me if my english is bad.

Comment: also i noted one more thing. i tried to load up the page2. and the result in console of getelementbyid is stull null in console of page1. Also in chrome tools ( Sources >> Pages ) , under localhost, i see the browser is only see page1.html + the static files. also the same for page2, there is only page2.html + static files

Comment: Can you go with displaying whatever you want to display on page 2, on page 1? You can simply show and hide a <div> whenever the user clicks the button (Which you're using now to navigate to page 2) . Here's an example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show

Comment: Actually i need to make a separate page for logging events which happens in page1.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data to page2 with GET param:

```js
//use this link param is name of param and values is the value of param
page2.htmnl?param=value;param2=value
```

In page2, in onload event you get values:

```js
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var param = url.searchParams.get("param");
var param2 = url.searchParams.get("param2");
console.log(param, param2);
```